# How to define the color of the underline of xAxis HighCharts

Tags: highcharts

I want the color of the underline to be different from the color of the text.

I already tried with

```
text-decoration: underline;
text-decoration-color: red;
```

but the underline takes the color of the text.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to change the xAxis line?  Or do you really want the xAxis labels to be underlined and that underline to be a different color than the text?  Can you provide an image of what you want?

Comment: I want the xAxis labels to be underlined and that underline to be a different color than the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Axis labels are **SVGs** by default. SVG can be styled via CSS but only a subset of CSS options is supported. For more advanced styling set `xAxis.labels.useHTML` to `true` and use this code:

```
.highcharts-xaxis-labels span {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: red;
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/ambL84be/

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.useHTML

Comment: Thanks bro, This was what I was needing.